# AJAX request sending null parameter to Java Spring controller

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

I am trying to do a simple POST request but for some reason my Integer parameter is null. This is something so basic, but I don't see what I am doing wrong here.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$rootScope.addUser = function(userId) {
            $http.post('/addUser', {
                params: {
                    user_id: userId
                }
            }).then(function(result) {
                $rootScope.userId = undefined;
            });
        };
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/addUser")
public void addTournament(@RequestParam(required = false) final Integer userId) {
    LOG.info("addUser: {}" , userId);
}
```

I have also tried doing `@RequestParam(name = "user_id") final Integer userId`, but even that does not work either!

In the end I will removed the 'required = false' parameter, but I left it there for now just to verify that the userId is indeed null.

The input is being grabbed from the user they input a number and click a button.

Answer (score 1):

The @RequestParam name does not match with the name of the attribute posted: **user_id** vs **userId**. Use `@RequestParam(name = "user_id") final Integer userId` to match them, or use the same request attribute and `@RequestParam` name.

[edit]

When I read `params: { ... }` I expected them to be additional request parameters instead of being part of the POST body. Could you try [POSTing](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) the data using:

```
$http.post('/addUser', { userId: userId }
```

And using the following `@PostMapping`:

```java
@PostMapping("/addUser")
public void addTournament(@RequestBody User user) {
    LOG.info("addUser: {}" , user.getUserId());
}

...

class User {
private String userId;

// getter and setter
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried that too but still no luck for some reason. The change I made was: @RequestParam(name = "user_id") final Integer userId, but now it does not print the log, so I am assuming it is still null for some reason...

Comment: I have updated my answer, I mistook the `params` attribute for additional request parameters instead of being part of the POST body.